# EV Certificate on browser

Tags: security, ssl

> How does the browser recognise that the presented certificate actually
>   is an EV certicate?

I went through [this article](https://www.globalsign.eu/ssl-information-center/telling-dv-and-ov-certificates-apart.html) but I couldn't figure out any thing for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The EV certificate is signed with a different CA certificate than a regular certificate.

Within the certificate is also an extended property that says it is an EV certificate.

In practice your web browser has different collections of CA certificates as well and recognizes that the server certificate was signed by the CA certificate from the EV collection and then displays a green URL bar.